# Public files are sent but route is not called

Tags: node.js, express

For some reason, "/" sends the public/index.html to the browser yet the express route in index.js does not fire.

index.js

```js
// Require packages
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const path = require("path");

// Create app
const app = express();

// Use cookie parser, body parser
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());


// Deal with templating and file serving shenanigans
app.engine("ejs", ejs.renderFile);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


// Start server
app.listen(1773, () => {
  console.log("I hope users aren't using weak passwords!");
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("I am not logged");
  res.send("I am not sent");
  // Async is needed for a function that occurs here.
})
```

There are no errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: IS there a physical .html file in the same folder?

Comment: It is in the public folder. The directory looks a follows.
- index.js
- public/index.html
- ...

Comment: Yep, thought so. The first answer explains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `express.static()` line is handling the request.  If it sees a request for `/`, then it looks in the folder you gave `express.static()` for an `index.html` file.  If it finds it, then it serves that file and the request is done - no later request handlers are called.

If you want your `/` route handler to get called, then you can either:

1. Remove the `index.html` file from the public directory
2. Tell `express.static()` not to match `index.html` with `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), {index: false}));`
3. Declare the `app.get("/", ...)` route before your `express.static()` route.
4. Change the `app.get("/", ...)` route to a different path that does not match something in the `public` directory and send your request to that other path.

Remember that Express matches routes in the order they are declared.  First one that matches wins.  So, if `express.static()` finds a match, it "handles" the request and no routes that are declared after it get a chance.

Comment: I did #3, thanks. I also decided to delete index.html and serve it in the EJS views and leave the file for CSS. Will it still server CSS to the client when I request for it in the index.ejs (previously html) file?

Comment: @willmaybe - Yes, it will serve CSS files if their path matches something that is found in the `public` directory you have `express.static()` pointing at.  There are many mistakes that people make in specifying those paths that cause it not to match, but if you get it right, it will work.  The first piece of advice is to use CSS paths in your HTML files that start with `/` so they are path absolute (not path relative) and do not depend upon the path of the container web page.